# Do JSTL tags automatically escape HTML?

Tags: java, jstl

In JSTL an expression such as

`<c:out value="${user.firstName}"/>` will escape any HTML as contained in user.firstName.

However, does it apply to all JSTL tags? For instance, will an expression like

```
href="<c:url value="/users/">
<c:param name="firstName" value="${user.firstName}"/>
</c:url>"
```

also escape HTML?

Comment: You know, you can write a simple test for it

Comment: I wouldn't want to have to test all JSTL tags myself if someone else has already spent the time to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, no tag except `<c:out>` escapes XML. For example: `<fmt:message>` doesn't escape XML. This allows placing HTML markup or escape sequences in the resource bundle.

`<c:param>` url-encodes the parameter value. But placing two `<c:param>` inside a single `<c:url>` will produce an unescaped `&`: `someUrl?foo=bar&baz=zim`. To properly escape this `&`, store the URL inside a variable, and use `<c:out>` or fn:escapeXml to escape the variable:

```
<c:url var="someUrl" var="theUnescapedUrl">
    <c:param name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <c:param name="baz" value="zim"/>
</c:url>
<a href="<c:out value='${theUnescapedUrl}'/>">click here</a>
```

or

```
<a href="${fn:escapeXml(theUnescapedUrl)}">click here</a>
```